# How to extract a the data-code attribute from a hidden element

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver

Using Watir-Webdriver, I want to be able to extract the 'data-code' value so I can enter it into the textfield on the page to unlock my locked account. Usually the code is emailed but in our test environment the code is hidden on the page, `<span data-code="123456">`. I want to grab the '123456' code and put it in the code textfield.

I've been unable to figure out how to do this. I'm guessing because there is no way to actually access the data code?

Is it possible to do that if this is the HTML?

```
<h1>
    Unlock your account
</h1>
<h2>
    Please enter the 6 digit code that was just sen…
    <span data-code="123456">
        test@email.com
    </span>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`attribute_value`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Element#attribute_value-instance_method) method:

```
browser.span.attribute_value('data-code')
#=> 123456
```

Answer (score 4):

You can retrieve data-* attributes similar to other standard attributes like id, name, etc. The method name is simply the data attribute with the dashes replaced by underscores:

```
p browser.span.data_code
#=> "123456"
```